# Writing migration tables for many-to-many relationships in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

I don't know how to write migration tables for many-to-many relationships. Here is my code:

```php
Schema::create('staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
        $table->char('link', 100)->nullable();
        $table->string('country')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('occupation')->nullable();
        $table->string('zipcode')->nullable();
        $table->string('photo')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps(); });

Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('staff_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('staff');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
Schema::create('role_staff', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('staff_id')->unsigned();;
        $table->foreign('staff_id')->references('id')->on('staff');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I am not sure I did right in terms of foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

> **Seems Perfect to me**

From you migrations script what I have understood is that you have 3 tables

- staff
- roles
- role_staff

Where **staff** is the master table where all the staff is stored and assignment of a role is done in **roles** table using the **id** column of the **staff** upon the **staff_id** column of the **roles** table.

Later on, you are storing all the references in a role_staff table where which **role** is given to **whom** is explained.

So By firing this query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM   role_staff AS rs 
       INNER JOIN staff s 
               ON rs.staff_id = s.id 
       INNER JOIN roles r 
              ON rs.role_id = r.id
```

Will give you a summary of all the staff and the roles assigned to them.

> Note: Do define your table [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) in each modal.

Comment: no issues but you can accept the answer as I tried your code it works fine
Please accept the answer and upvote :) Thanks.